# nginx config and php block acess to css

Tags: php, nginx

i have this config for nginx

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ ^/([a-fA-F0-9]+) {
        rewrite ^/([a-fA-F0-9]+) /index.php?id=$1 last;
    }
}
```

and this php

```
<?php

require_once('_admin/config.php');

$capturedIP = getIP();
$requestUri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$pathParts = explode('/', $requestUri);
$valor = end($pathParts);

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://uvinha.games/check-iphash");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json"));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode(array("ip" => $capturedIP, "hash" => $valor)));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

$responseData = json_decode($response, true);

if (!$responseData["blocked"]) {
    
    clearSession();


    if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
        unset($_SESSION['id']);
    }

    $hash = getHash();
    Acesso::registrarAcesso($hash);
    if (isMobile()) {
        header('Location: mobile/fim.php?hash='.$hash);
    } else {
        header('Location: home.php?hash='.$hash);
    }
}else {
    // if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '.css') !== false) {
    //     return;
    // }
    echo "BLOCKED!";
}


?>
```

When I access my domain for example:

http://entrardomain.com/5b8e81547053379a5a231576a614850b?u1=636d566e61584e796157393051476876644731686157777559323974&t1=bra

it takes the 5b8e81547053379a5a231576a614850b makes the curl and returns me if it is allowed or not, however when redirecting to home.php?hash= everything is displayed, except the .css, images and .js files are displayed normally, but the rest is blocked, returns me the else error, which in this case is echo "BLOCKED!", what to do to solve this problem?

Comment: Your regular expression matches any URL that starts with a number or letter. You need to place a `$` at the end of the expression to exclude URLs that contain a `.`. Try: `location ~ ^/([a-fA-F0-9]+)$ { ... }`